# Installing HAProxy on CentOS 6.3?

Tags: haproxy, rpm, repository, epel

This is a weird one.

I've installed the EPEL for CentOS 6 via

```
# rpm -Uvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
```

The tried to install HAProxy:

```
# yum update
# yum install haproxy
```

But receive:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp.heanet.ie
 * epel: fedora.mirror.nexicom.net
 * extras: ftp.heanet.ie
 * updates: ftp.heanet.ie
Setting up Install Process
No package haproxy available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Can't figure out why haproxy is not found! Help?

Comment: Why the downvote? In this case, the package is [**not in the El6 repositories**](http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/repoview/haproxy.html), contrary to the installation instructions provided in several online tutorials.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[The haproxy package has been removed from EPEL](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=913209) because it is [now included with RHEL 6.4](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/6.4_Release_Notes/networking.html) (and will be in derivative distributions after they build 6.4).

> Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.4 introduces the haproxy package as a Technology Preview.

If you need it *now*, you can obtain [Red Hat's 6.4 SRPM](http://ftp.redhat.com/pub/redhat/linux/enterprise/6Server/en/os/SRPMS/haproxy-1.4.22-3.el6.src.rpm) and rebuild it on your system (the same way CentOS will shortly). For example:

```
wget http://ftp.redhat.com/pub/redhat/linux/enterprise/6Server/en/os/SRPMS/haproxy-1.4.22-3.el6.src.rpm
mock -r epel-6-x86_64 haproxy-1.4.22-3.el6.src.rpm
```

Otherwise you can wait for CentOS 6.4 and then it will be available through the base repository.

Comment: EPEL is gross; it is nice to see this getting baked into sensible production OSes like RedHat and Debian.

Answer (score 6):

HAProxy is not part of the general subscription.

You'll need to add the "RHEL Server Load Balancer (v. 6 for 64-bit x86_64)"
channel to your entitlements before you can "yum install haproxy"

Comment: This would be correct except that this is CentOS, not RHEL.

Comment: @Jacob True, but this will be useful to RHEL users who find this question.

Answer (score 2):

You took the [right steps](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/setting-up-haproxy), however it appears as though HAProxy is no longer available in the EPEL software repository for EL6 distributions.

The old links no longer work.
http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/repoview/haproxy.html

Comment: I was thinking this might me the reason. Any idea as to why it'd be removed from the EPEL repos? I Googled but couldn't find any info (blogs) as to why its been removed.

Comment: Neither could I! No explanation. I'll dig a little deeper.

Comment: Thanks. I try and do a bit of digging myself! Removal from the repo was the last thing I would have suspected!

Answer (score 2):

HAProxy is not part of CentOS, but it used to be part of the Fedora EPEL repository. However [since RHEL6.4](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/6.4_Release_Notes/networking.html) HAProxy is part of Red Hat's Load Balancer product/addon and EPEL's policy to not conflict with Red Hat's offerings resulted in HAProxy to be removed from Fedora's EPEL repository.

Since HAProxy is part of RHEL's released product (albeit as an addon and a Technology Preview) it means CentOS does include it in their normal CentOS-6.4 offering (much like it includes other addon products, e.g. High-Availability). This means CentOS includes it in its main repository.

Beware that, while it may not be obvious to a lot of CentOS users, haproxy is a Technology Preview, which means that it is not (yet) supported by Red Hat, either because Red Hat does not feel comfortable supporting it already, or because they expect another major/minor release update, or the roadmap for the product is still changing (new functionality, known bugs). Whatever the reason the lack of support means there are reasons for Red Hat to assume the support cannot be guaranteed, which is something a CentOS user should be aware of as the CentOS project does not specifically mention this.

Answer (score 1):

Another method would be just downloading the epel rpm and doing a yum localinstall.

A 10 second search and I found the beta package available:

```
wget ftp://rpmfind.net/linux/epel/beta/6/x86_64/haproxy-1.4.8-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
yum localinstall haproxy-1.4.8-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
```